# tkinter simpledialog not working on Mac 10.14

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm creating a UI with python 3.7 with tkinter. I have a button that should open a dialog and ask for a string input, in windows it works entirely as expected but for some reason it won't work on any of 3 Macs I've tried. On the Macs the main window goes gray on top and you can't interact with it, so it's as if a dialog window has opened, but the dialog window is nowhere to be found. Python is not crashing or giving any error messages either. It's baffling to me that I have not been able to find any similar problems searching online.

The button calls this method:

```
    def add_goal(self):
        newgoal = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "What goal would you like to begin tracking?", parent=self.root)
        self.goal_list.goals.append(goal.Goal(newgoal,0,0))
        self.set_listbox()
        print(self.goal_list)
```

I have tested the button with only a print statement so I know the button works.
I have also tested the button with only the simpledialog line so I know the other parts aren't causing a problem. I have also tried simpledialog.askinteger just to see and that didn't work either.

If relevant I'm doing `from tkinter import simpledialog` at the top.
And again this all works perfectly fine on windows.

Thanks for any help, I can post the entire code if anyone wants but I don't *think* any of it is relevant.

Comment: create minimal working code so we could run it. You can also use `Toplevel()` + `Entry()` + `Button()` to create own window.

Comment: Good call, reducing my code to the minimal necessary to illustrate the problem helped me figure out what was wrong.

The line `self.root.attributes("-topmost", True)` seems like it was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was using `root.attributes("-topmost", True)`, the code was derived from a program that was meant to be at the front of the screen at all times which is why that line was there to begin with, but I realized it was no longer necessary and it seems to be the source of the problem.